# Pandas limit Series/DataFrame to range of values of one column

Tags: pandas

I’d like to have a function df_out(df_in,val_min,val_max) that makes a sorted series/dataframe from another series/dataframe by picking rows where values in one column are within a defined range.
E.g., if df_in looks like this:

```
Name   Age

John  13

Jack  19

Sylvia 21

Anna 14

Carlos 15

Vladimir 30

Gustav 28

Amie 24
```

I’d like df_out(18,25) to look like this:

```
Name Age

Jack 19

Sylvia 21

Amie 24
```

What's the most "pythonic" way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Why use a function when it is so easily done natively?

```
>>> df[df.Age.between(18, 25)]
     Name  Age
1    Jack   19
2  Sylvia   21
7    Amie   24

>>> df[df.Age.between(19, 24, inclusive=False)]
     Name  Age
2  Sylvia   21
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have it in a DataFrame `df`, with columns `Name`, and `Age`, you can simply use

```
df[(min_val <= df.Age) & (df.Age <= max_val)]
```

Note that you need to use the seemingly-redundant parentheses in the above expression, due to operator precedence.

---

You can create this into a function like so:

```
def df_limited(df, min_val, max_val):
    return df[(min_val <= df.Age) & (df.Age <= max_val)]
```

Comment: Thanks. And is there a way to create a function for this, i.e. like: df_limited(df, min_val, max_val) = df[(min_val <= df.Age) & (df.Age <= max_val)] ?

Comment: Great, thanks. I have a follow-up question. How can I interpolate over the resulting histogram and plot the result? Do I need to create a function from the data frame first?

Comment: I suggest you ask that as a new question. StackOverflow isn't really built for a discussion on followup questions in the comments section. I'm sure people will answer it.