# Smooth histogram from data in column in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas

This is a follow-up to this question: [Pandas limit Series/DataFrame to range of values of one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513634/pandas-limit-series-dataframe-to-range-of-values-of-one-column)

I'd next like to histogram the numbers in the "Age" column and then smooth the result (to reduce scatter). What's an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? It's easy. Look up Matplotlib's hist function, or pandas's hist function.

Comment: [Density plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150171/how-to-create-a-density-plot-in-matplotlib), [Plotting probability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415455/plotting-probability-density-function-by-sample-with-matplotlib), or maybe you just want `df['Age'].plot(kind='density')` or `df['Age'].hist()`.  I'm personally unclear on what you mean by "then smooth the result".

Comment: It's easy to make a histogram, but I'm having some formatting issues when trying to smooth over it. It seems like the only way is to produce a new function function from the histogram and smooth/interpolate over it using scipy's interpolate, but I thought there may be a more pythonic way to do it, e.g., with a pandas-native function?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/) and its function [distplot](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) which plot by default a kernel density estimate and histogram with bin size determined automatically.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Some test data
np.random.seed(33454)
df = pd.DataFrame({'nb': np.random.randint(0, 1000, 100)})
df.sort_values('nb', inplace=True)

ax = sns.distplot(df['nb'])
```

[image]